# Django - Using mysql.connector.django gives TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-admin, mysql-connector-python

When using Django with `mysql-connector-python` and the Admin views, and trying to list data from one of the tables, the page fails with `TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting`. The Django Rest Framework APIs work and return data for the same table.

Has anyone seen this before? Any ideas to fix this?

Same code base works on a Postgres backend.

Versions:

```
django==2.0.13
djangorestframework==3.8.2
mysql-connector-python==8.0.5
```

Stacktrace:

```
2019-05-23 15:06:08,121 CST [ERROR] [PID:99924] [TNAME:Thread-8] django.request| Internal Server Error: /admin/api/source/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xbox/IdeaProjects/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 35, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/xbox/IdeaProjects/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 158, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/xbox/IdeaProjects/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 156, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "/Users/xbox/IdeaProjects/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 106, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "/Users/xbox/IdeaProjects/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 83, in rendered_content
    content = template.render(context, self._request)
  File "/Users/xbox/IdeaProjects/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/Users/xbox/IdeaProjects/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 175, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/Users/xbox/IdeaProjects/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 167, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/xbox/IdeaProjects/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 943, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/Users/xbox/IdeaProjects/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 910, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/xbox/IdeaProjects/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 155, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/Users/xbox/IdeaProjects/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 167, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/xbox/IdeaProjects/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 943, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/Users/xbox/IdeaProjects/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 910, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/xbox/IdeaProjects/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 155, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/Users/xbox/IdeaProjects/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 167, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/xbox/IdeaProjects/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 943, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/Users/xbox/IdeaProjects/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 910, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/xbox/IdeaProjects/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 67, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/xbox/IdeaProjects/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 943, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/Users/xbox/IdeaProjects/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 910, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/xbox/IdeaProjects/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 67, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/xbox/IdeaProjects/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 943, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/Users/xbox/IdeaProjects/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 910, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/xbox/IdeaProjects/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/library.py", line 214, in render
    _dict = self.func(*resolved_args, **resolved_kwargs)
  File "/Users/xbox/IdeaProjects/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templatetags/admin_list.py", line 379, in date_hierarchy
    } for day in days]
  File "/Users/xbox/IdeaProjects/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 272, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/Users/xbox/IdeaProjects/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1182, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/Users/xbox/IdeaProjects/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 178, in __iter__
    for row in compiler.results_iter(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size):
  File "/Users/xbox/IdeaProjects/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1019, in results_iter
    results = self.execute_sql(MULTI, chunked_fetch=chunked_fetch, chunk_size=chunk_size)
  File "/Users/xbox/IdeaProjects/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1055, in execute_sql
    sql, params = self.as_sql()
  File "/Users/xbox/IdeaProjects/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 461, in as_sql
    where, w_params = self.compile(self.where) if self.where is not None else ("", [])
  File "/Users/xbox/IdeaProjects/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 393, in compile
    sql, params = node.as_sql(self, self.connection)
  File "/Users/xbox/IdeaProjects/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/where.py", line 80, in as_sql
    sql, params = compiler.compile(child)
  File "/Users/xbox/IdeaProjects/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 393, in compile
    sql, params = node.as_sql(self, self.connection)
  File "/Users/xbox/IdeaProjects/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py", line 160, in as_sql
    lhs_sql, params = self.process_lhs(compiler, connection)
  File "/Users/xbox/IdeaProjects/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py", line 155, in process_lhs
    db_type, field_internal_type) % lhs_sql
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade to the latest Connector/Python version (8.0.16 at this time).

```
pip install --upgrade mysql-connector-python
```